# Trigger after insert: can't update a record with no direct connection

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, after-trigger, helper

I have this construction:
[image]

If we create a Factory 2 with `InDateTime__c` = `OutDateTime__c` of the Tool 1 with the same Opportunity 1 (with another Factory 1 with the same Opportunity 1 relationship), this Tool 1 will get `Parts__c` from the Factory 2.

Sometimes it works with `Parts__c` field and sometimes not. I don't know where is the problem. Can you help me please?

Helper:

```
public static void updateTool(List<Factory__c> createFactoryTrigger){
    Map<Id, Tool__c> mapToConnect = new Map<Id, Tool__c>();
    List<Tool__c> listToUpsert = new List<Tool__c>();
    List<Tool__c> actualTools = [SELECT OutDateTime__c, Factory__r.Opportunity__c, Parts__c FROM Tool__c
                                WHERE OutDateTime__c >= : DateTime.now()];

    for(Tool__c tool : actualTools){
        mapToConnect.put(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c, tool);
    }

    for(Factory__c factory : createFactoryTrigger){
        Id opportunityId = factory.Opportunity__c;

        DateTime toolDT = mapToConnect.get(opportunityId).OutDateTime__c;
        Date toolD = date.newinstance(toolDT.year(), toolDT.month(), toolDT.day());
        DateTime factoryDT = factory.InDateTime__c;
        Date factoryD = date.newinstance(factoryDT.year(), factoryDT.month(), factoryDT.day());

        if(mapToConnect.containsKey(opportunityId) && toolD == factoryD && factory.Count__c > 0){ 
            mapToConnect.get(opportunityId).Parts__c = String.valueOf(factory.Count__c) + ' parts';
            listToUpsert.add(mapToConnect.get(opportunityId));
        }
    }
    upsert listToUpsert Id;
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger ToolsTrigger on Factory__c (after insert) { 
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
        triggerHelper.updateTool(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually multiple problems in code.

1. Below query is returning all tools after `now` and not specific to opportunities which are in trigger context of factory. Its a big performance problem.

   ```
   SELECT OutDateTime__c, Factory__r.Opportunity__c, Parts__c FROM Tool__c
                                WHERE OutDateTime__c >= : DateTime.now()
   ```
2. If there are multiple tools under opportunity you are referring to only 1 tool for given opportunity. (because it will be replacing previous tool for same opp)

   ```
   for(Tool__c tool : actualTools){
       mapToConnect.put(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c, tool);
   }
   ```

There is 1 tool per factory but multiple factories per opportunity. This means there will be multiple tools per opportunity.

3. Because of above point, you are comparing only 1 tool under opportunity with factory.
4. You said in question you want to compare `datetime` but you are comparing only dates.

   ```
   toolD == factoryD
   ```

**Try below method:**

Here, we are constructing `mapToConnect` by using both opp id and date as keys.

```
public static void updateTool(List<Factory__c> createFactoryTrigger){
    Map<Id, Factory__c> newFactoriesMap = (Map<Id, Factory__c>)Trigger.newMap;
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Map<Date,Tool__c>> mapToConnect = new Map<Id, Map<Date,Tool__c>>();
    List<Tool__c> listToUpsert = new List<Tool__c>();

    for(Factory__c factory : createFactoryTrigger){
        oppIds.add(factory.Opportunity__c);
    }

    List<Tool__c> actualTools = [SELECT OutDateTime__c, Factory__r.Opportunity__c, Parts__c FROM Tool__c
                                 WHERE Factory__r.Opportunity__c = :oppIds];

    for(Tool__c tool : actualTools){
        if(!mapToConnect.containsKey(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c))
            mapToConnect.put(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c, new Map<Date,Tool__c>());

        Date toolDate = date.newinstance(tool.OutDateTime__c.year(), tool.OutDateTime__c.month(), tool.OutDateTime__c.day());
        mapToConnect.get(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c).put(toolDate,tool);
    }

    for(Factory__c factory : createFactoryTrigger){
        if(mapToConnect.containsKey(factory.Opportunity__c) && 
           mapToConnect.get(factory.Opportunity__c).containsKey(factory.InDateTime__c) && 
           factory.Count__c > 0) 
        {
            mapToConnect.get(factory.Opportunity__c).get(factory.InDateTime__c).Parts__c = String.valueOf(factory.Count__c) + ' parts';
            listToUpsert.add(mapToConnect.get(factory.Opportunity__c).get(factory.InDateTime__c));
        }
    }
    upsert listToUpsert Id;
}
```

PS: There might be typos in code. As I dont have these objects, I cannot compile this method. But it gives overall idea how to handle multiple tools and how to construct `mapToConnect`.

Comment: No, I want to compare date from datetime. No, it is not multiple (each Factory has only 1 Tool). And I really didn't understand about `now`. Can you tell me, please, how can I fix my problem?

Comment: From your design its clear that there might be multiple factories under each opportunity (although 1 tool for a factory). So it makes multiple tools for opportunity

Comment: It can be multiple factories under each opportunity. But each Factory has only 1 tool. Always. It's an inside rule.

Comment: added in point-2 and also suggested method. There might be typos in code (Since I dont have those objects, I cant compile it)

Comment: Thank you. But where do we use `newFactoriesMap`? And I also got here `if(!mapToConnect.containsKey(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c))
            mapToConnect.put(tool.Factory__r.Opportunity__c, new Map<Date,Tool__c>);
` Unexpected token ')'. Hmmm.

Comment: it should have been `new Map<Date,Tool__c>()`. As I said, i cannot compile, pls correct such typos. (corrected in answer)